# Why is this variable not being passed in the POST request?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I am trying to do a simple POST request via AJAX, but I keep getting 500 errors.  In an effort to figure out where the problem is, I added print statements after every if conditional.  See my view below.

```
if request.is_ajax():
    print "request is ajax"
    object_name = request.POST.get('entryname')
    print object_name
    targetobject = Entry.objects.get(headline=object_name)
    if request.user.username == targetobject.author:
        print "current user is author" 
        targetobject.delete()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/storefront/')
```

The only thing that prints to the console (other than the 500 error) is "request is ajax", and "None".  This tells me that something is wrong with 'object_name' or 'entryname'.  Below is the jQuery AJAX.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var my_app = {
      username: "{{ request.user.username }}"  
    };
</script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".delete_button").click(function() {
        var entryname = $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/accounts/" + my_app.username + "/listview/",
            data: {'entryname': entryname},
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>

<a href="" class="delete_button" id="{{ i.headline }}">del</a>
```

And, this error in the console

```
DoesNotExist: Entry matching query does not exist.
```

Where did I go wrong?  Is the error in the jQuery or my view method?

Comment: I see a `var id` but not a `var entryname` - are you setting it somewhere?

Comment: Put your code in a Try Cache and see what the error is. 500 is server side so start there.

Comment: @souldeux I edited the post above , set entryname and remove var id.  The only difference this made is Django Console now prints None for object_none.

Comment: I think you should pass your data like this: data:  {'entryname': entryname}

Comment: @kaveh, thank you.  I changed it but still same error and object_name prints None still

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks like it's looking for the `id` of the element with class `delete_button`. Does your template contain an element with that class? If so, what is its `id`? That is the value that should be passed as `entryname`, but if there's no such element in your template then it would make sense that a value of `None` is being passed (as you mentioned in your comments). Try adding the `delete_button` class to your link tag.

Comment: If it works, then yes - like that. If not, try changing it from an `a` tag to a `button`. Sorry, I am on mobile or I would test it myself.

Comment: I think it worked.  I mean object_name now prints the correct name in the console and there are no more errors.  However, for some reason the object is not being deleted.

Comment: Is that second `if` block getting executed? And is `author` a custom user profile or auth model, or anything like that? `if request.user.username == targetobject.author` may need to be something like `if request.user.username == targetobject.author.user.username`.

Comment: if request.user.username == targetobject.author.username worked.  You are a genius!

Comment: @Dr.Donnaloia, one last thing you need to do: pass csrfmiddlewaretoken as part of your data. Probably that's the reason there's no data in your POST. Do it like this: data: {'entryname': entryname, csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'}